# how do i get my emails back onto the server after download with outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

how do i restore my emails into my freemaile-box after downloading all of them 
via outlook,having outlook delete them on the server?

cheers, 
Frederik

Answer (score 3):

If you selected delete from server and polled, they're gone.  If your mail server supports it, you could set up a second connection as IMAP, then manually transfer the emails from your local machine back to the remote server.  Just make sure to turn of POP polling first, and when you're ready to start again, make sure you don't delete messages from the server.